# Rangy deserialize doesn't show span id's

Tags: rangy

I'm using

```
highlighter.deserialize(item.rangyObject);
```

to create my span's and highlights from a DB.
It looks like the deserialize function doesn't creates them with any id's.

Rangy's restoreSelection function does create them.
Should I be using this method? Is there away to tweak the deserialize function so it will reproduce the span's with id's?